# CSS change menu color on fixed-header-scroll

Tags: css

Is there a way to change the menu links color on a specific WP page only by CSS?

Here's my code:

```
.page-id-20 #menu>ul>li>a, #menu>div>ul>li>a {
color: #ffffff;
}
.page-id-20 .fixed-header-scroll #menu>div>ul>li>a {
color: #000000;
}
```

but it doesn't work...

Comment: What doesn't work? Where's the HTML? Also, your CSS is written poorly.

Comment: When you check you body tag on a specific page, the name of the page should be added as a class.  target using that class. Also share your html because you make not be targeting it right